# How to map Ctrl+Esc to another key in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to map `Esc` to left `Control` and `Control+ESC` to the original `ESC`. Unfortunately when I press `Control+ESC`, the *Windows start menu* is opened. How to solve this issue?

```
Esc::Send {LControl Down}
^Esc::Esc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$` modifier before `Esc` hotkey definition to prevent launching it from another hotkey:

```
$Esc::Send {LControl Down}
^Esc::Send {Esc}
```

After this change, definitions are working as you expect.